# What is the logic behind the below example of array and pointer?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, printf

I am unable to figure out the difference between array and pointer's working and how they are interrelated to each other.

The code:

```
char str[]="banti is a nice girl";
    char *ptr=str+6;
    printf("%s",ptr)
```

The output: `is a nice girl`

1. I didn't use dereferencing operator in my `printf` statement,
   **why it is giving me the content of the array, and not the address?**
2. When I write `char*ptr=str[6]` i get `Error: cannot convert char to char*` -
   **what does this error mean?**
3. Is it so that to refer to an array address we need to put `&str[6]` but we do not need to put while we do in `str+6`? If it is so, what's the logic behind it?

Comment: This code cannot compile, you are missing a `*` in the first row.

Comment: `str[6]` is `char`, not `char *`. `str` represent the address of the first element of `str` has been evaluated as a pointer.

Comment: I'd recommend you to learn C++ before you try learn C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a code such as below

```
char str[]="banti is a nice girl";
printf("%s",str);
```

then the array str is converted to a pointer to its first element of type `char *`

So the code above is equivalent to

```
char str[]="banti is a nice girl";
char *ptr=str;
printf("%s",ptr);
```

When function printf process format specifier `%s` it considers the corresponding argument as a pointer of type `char *` and outputs all characters pointed by the pointer until it meets a terminating zero.

So in this code snipped

```
char str[]="banti is a nice girl";
char *ptr=str + 6;
printf("%s",ptr);
```

You simply shift right the pointer to 6 characters and the function printf starts to output characters from `str + 6`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `str` is of type `char[21]`. That is, an array containing all the characters in `banti is a nice girl` plus the nul-terminator, `\0`. Now, in C and C++, arrays can easily decay to pointers to their first element. This happens in this expression:

```
str + 6
```

Here, `str` can be taken to mean `&str[0]`. Incrementing that by 6 gives you a pointer to the 7th position in `str` (the address of `str[6]`), i.e. the `i` in `is`. The `ptr` is initialized to hold the value of this pointer. When you pass `ptr` to `printf`, it prints the string starting from that position, until the nul terminator.

> Now, I didn't use dereferencing operator in my printf statement, why it is giving me the context of the array, and not the address?

Because you are telling `printf` that you are passing it a pointer to a nul-terminated string so that it can print out the string. That is what `"%s"` means. `printf` knows how to print a nul-terminated string. It prints characters until it finds the nul terminator `\0`.

> Why it gives error if I write char*ptr=str[6]; Error: cannot convert char to char*;

Because `str[6]` is a `char` and you cannot initialize a `char*` from a `char`. That is what the compiler error is telling you.

Comment: Maybe a small reference to some more explanation: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html

Comment: Lets say int str[2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; int *ptr=str+4;now to print the value "6", i would write printf("%d",*ptr) and not printf("%d",ptr) which we did in the case of string in above question. Why there is a difference in syntax here and why my output was not 6 7 8 as it happened in my above question ?

Comment: @Rishab The difference is `printf` assumes you are passing a nul-terminated string when you use `%s` and pass a `char*`. It prints characters until it finds a nul terminator.

Comment: So, we use don't use dereferencing operator (*) while fetching the context of array string (since we use printf("%s",ptr) ), but we gotta use * while fetching the context of array int (since we used printf("%d",*ptr) to get the particular value ) ? Reason behind it ?

Comment: @Rishab `"%d"` if for signed integers, not pointers. So it would make no sense to pass a pointer when `printf` expects an `int`. Try reading [some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: So, down-voter (or anyone else who might have an idea), what is wrong with this answer? It would be interesting to know.

Answer (score 0):

it is advancing the `str` base address by 6 which will now points `is a nice girl`

try this:

```
main()
{

       char str[]="banti is a nice girl";
       char *ptr=&str[6];
       printf("%s",ptr);
}
```

**try to print it:**

```
 printf("%d",str[6]);  // return first character ascii value
   printf("\n%d",(str+6)); // return the address 
   printf("\n%d",&str[6]); // return the address
```

`&str[6]` and `(str+6)` both indicates address but `str[6]` indicate the first character of string.

Comment: But why it is happening.Please read the question above again.

Comment: you should assign the address of that location.

Comment: ASCII is probably not the target character set/encoding. The array `str` is a sequence of byte-sized code units. Which encoding of which character set is unspecified. It's like to be Windows-1252 or equiv or Unicode/UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

the error that you are receiving in

```
Why it gives error if I write char*ptr=str[6]; Error: cannot convert char to char*;
```

that is because you are doing something like this

```
char* str = *(str + 6);
```

as you know str[6] would be evaluated to *(str + 6), which is equal to `i`. that `i` you are trying to store in char pointer str..

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that you simply don't understand arrays and pointers in C and C++.

## How arrays works in C and C++?

```
char str[]="banti is a nice girl";
```

This line creates an array of chars.

```
['b','a','n','t','i',' ','i','s',' ','a',' ','n','i','c','e',' ','g','i','r','l','\0']
  ^
 str
```

Array is what you have between `[]`, and it's stored somewhere in memory;
you can access to it through the pointer `str`.

`str+6` means *pointer `str` moved `6` elements after the element it's pointing to.*

```
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19   20
{'b','a','n','t','i',' ','i','s',' ','a',' ','n','i','c','e',' ','g','i','r','l','\0'}
  ^                       ^
 str                    str+6
```

`str[6]` means `*(str+6)`, which means *get the `str+6`'s value*.

`str` is `char*`, `str+6` is also `char*`, but `*(str+6)` is a `char`, equal to `'i'`;
`char` cannot be implicitly converted to `char*`.

## What does the `printf`, when you give it `%s` in format string?

It expects that you give it `char*` (*pointer to `char`*);
it makes copy of the `char*` you give (let's name the copy `copy`), and does something like:

```
while( (*copy)!='\0'){
    //print out *copy;
    ++copy;
}
```

So, it prints `char` after `char` from the array, until it meets `'\0'`.